# Is there any noteworthy difference between "expend" and "spend"?

Tags: word-choice

> *40% of household income in Turkey was **expended** on food and drink, compared to 20% in Spain and 10% in the UK.*

This is a sentence I wrote, and Grammarly corrected ***expended*** to ***spent***. According to what I see in the dictionary, there's no significant difference between the two words, or at least in this example, so I wonder why Grammarly suggested it.

Comment: **Spend** is normally used with money, **expend** more commonly with energy or resources. Generally, Grammarly will tell you to use a simple word rather than a more complex word because it's bad style to use unnecessarily complex language.

Comment: expend is not used for money spent on things. What StuartF says is accurate. No one would say some percentage of income was expended on. It is a misuse of the the term.

Comment: But according to the OALD and Cambridge Dictionary, __expend__ means __"to use or spend a lot of time, money, energy, etc."__

Answer (score 0):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary, [expend](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expend) is a formal word. That means it's fine to use it in formal writing (and I would say that the sentence you quoted is formal writing), but you wouldn't use it in speech.

In terms of meaning, I would be more inclined to use expend to talk about time/energy/money that I felt was being wasted.

Why does Grammarly dislike expend? No idea: maybe they disapprove of formal words.

Comment: Others say that it's only used to connote depletion, not allocation. Do you agree?

Comment: @KenAdams Both spend and expend are about depletion. You have money in your pocket, you spend some, the money in your pocket is depleted.  Both can also be about allocation. This Ngram search shows that "Expenditure budget" is much more widely used than "Spending budget", and a budget is entirely about allocation, not depletion. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expenditure+budget%2Cspending+budget&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: "Expenditure budget" is widely used, so "expending one's budget" and "expending one's money" are totally fine. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @KenAdams in formal, written English, yes. It's not something that you would ever say.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the *ex* prefix  can draw attention to outflow and the fact that what is  being spent is not limitless.

Not that the word is being used in that way in the Turkey example. Like Grammarly,  I also find the usage there a bit odd, since "expend" connotes *depletion* not *allocation*. We wouldn't say "The company *expended* $50 million on R&D".

> Take care to pace yourself. It's a long race, and you don't want to expend all your energy early on.

Comment: Why are definitions in dictionaries so misleading? According to a lot of different dictionaries, __expend__ means __"to use or spend a lot of time, money, energy, etc."__. They don't say anything about how it's really used. I feel a bit frustrated as an English learner to receive conflicting information all the time :<.

Comment: Lexiocgraphers will ususally try to put the "bullseye" usage (i.e. the most central one) first and give other uses which don't quite hit the bullseye as secondary or tertiary meanings. Merriam-Webster, for example, offers "to pay out" as the first definition and "to make use of for a specific purpose" as a second definition (but their example sentence is a bad example of this meaning, which I don't think  is warranted in the first place); then at the bottom of their entry they point to the phrasal verb **use up**, which IMO is the bullseye usage, as it focuses on the notion of *depletion*.

Comment: The definition I put above is from the Cambridge Dictionary and the OALD, two of the biggest online dictionaried in my opinion. What about them?

Comment: Learners dictionaries like OALD are poor resources when it comes to *nuance*. And I find the entry in Cambridge to be of low quality. Perhaps there's a transatlantic difference here (though I don't think so).  Collins dictionary gives the 'use up" meaning as secondary under the "American English" rubric. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/expend

Comment: Hard to demonstrate this with ngram, but here's an attempt: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expend+limitless%2Cspend+limitless&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3